# Check the empty content in array

Tags: php

I have got an array that contains different kinds of element.
The array can have different dimension in different fields.

I want to write a function to check if there are some variables in the array are empty.

The sample array is like the following.

```
$array = new array(
         'a'=>'A', 
         'b' => new array('B',''), 
         'c'=> ''
);
```

Comment: you mean if values of a key are empty?

Comment: Yes. The point is I cannot use simple looping to check the empty field because the dimension of the array cannot be controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will go through all the arrays:

```
$isEmpty = checkArray( $arr );

if ( $isEmpty ) {
    echo "there are empties!";
} else {
    echo "no empties!";
}


function checkArray( $array ) {

    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {

        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            if ( checkArray( $value ) ) return true;
        } else {
            if ( empty( $value ) ) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Recursion is a great thing here.  I think I can even use is_array to make the function more readable.

Comment: good point, I updated the answer with `is_array` as per your suggestion for other folks that may use it

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```